# How to identify device moves up and down CoreMotion iOS?

Tags: ios, gyroscope, core-motion

I'm doing a research to get the device up and down movements. What I actually need is, When a user moving by a vehicle I want to identify if the device is continuously going up and down(when on a rigid road). I tried to do it with Core motion gyroscope.

```
self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];


//Gyroscope
if([self.motionManager isGyroAvailable])
{
    /* Start the gyroscope if it is not active already */
    if([self.motionManager isGyroActive] == NO)
    {
        /* Update us 2 times a second */
        [self.motionManager setGyroUpdateInterval:1.0f / 2.0f];

        /* Add on a handler block object */

        /* Receive the gyroscope data on this block */
        [self.motionManager startGyroUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                        withHandler:^(CMGyroData *gyroData, NSError *error)
         {
             NSString *x = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"X: %.02f",gyroData.rotationRate.x];
             self.xAxisLabel.text = x;

             NSString *y = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Y: %.02f",gyroData.rotationRate.y];
             self.yAxisLabel.text = y;

             NSString *z = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Z: %.02f",gyroData.rotationRate.z];
             self.zAxisLabel.text = z;
         }];
    }
}
```

What is the best way to do this and how can I solve this with the gyroscope?

Comment: You can use the concept of accelerometer for your problem.

Comment: Yes, use the accelerometer for directional movement. Gyroscope is for angular movement.